# Как найти k-тую порядковую статистику всех сумм двух массивов?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Кратко о ограничениях на программу:

```
Час: 3 секунды;
Память: 256 МБ;
Размерность масивов: n = 200000,m = 200000;
Размер одного елемента масива a или b: 10^9;
K-тая порядковая статистика (k): 1 <= k <= n * m;
```

Моя идея была в том чтобы найти все сумы 2х масивов и тогда за время O(n) найти k-тую порядковую статистику,но при ограничения на задачу 3 секунды и 256MB оно не проходит по памяти изза хранения 4*10^10 в масиве.

Зарание спасибо за идею или код на каком небудь языке.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long
int main()
{
    ll n1, n2;
    cin >> n1;
    ll arr1[n1];
    for (ll i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        cin >> arr1[i];
    }
    cin >> n2;
    ll arr2[n2];
    for (ll i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        cin >> arr2[i];
    }
    ll k;
    cin >> k;
    vector <ll> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
            a.push_back(arr1[i] + arr2[j]);
        }
    }
    nth_element(a.begin(), a.begin() + k-1, a.end());
    cout << a[k-1];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а почему 4*10^10 не проходит? Это же 40 мегабайт, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: начальные данные являются упорядоченными или нет?

Comment: начальные даные могут быть упорядочиные или нет,ну как какой тест

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, это ~37Гб

Comment: @isnullxbh ну да, чет затупил...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отсортируйте массивы, если это ещё не сделано.

Если записать один массив по горизонтали, другой по вертикали, и создать таблицу из сумм, то в этой таблице будут отсортированы как строки, так столбцы (т.н. таблица Юнга). Отмечу, что для решения данной задачи строить реальную таблицу и занимать место в памяти не требуется, обращение к значению `S[i][j]` будет просто означать сумму `A[i] + B[j]`

Наибольшая сумма `SMax` находится в ячейке `S[0,0]`, наименьшая `SMin` - в ячейке `S[N-1,M-1]`.

Найдём такое значение `X` в диапазоне `SMin..SMax`, что `K-1` ячеек таблицы больше его, с помощью бинарного поиска. Этот поиск потребует `Log(SMax-SMin)` этапов.

А каждый этап можно выполнить за `O(N+M)` шагов, используя сканирование таблицы, начиная с правого верхнего (или левого нижнего) угла `S[0, M-1]` и подсчитывая количество элементов, меньших X. Это сканирование будет выполняться за линейное время, т.к. шаг делается либо вниз, либо влево. Псевдокод (не проверял):

```
int i = 0;
int j = m-1; 
inc count = 0;
while ( i < n && j >= 0 )
{
    if (A[i] + B[j] > x ) //идём вниз
    {
       count += j + 1;  //часть строки с начала по текущую ячейку больше x
       i++;
    }
  else 
    j--;         //идём влево
}
```

Таким образом, время работы (не считая сортировку) будет `O((N+M)*Log(SMax-SMin))`, а затраты памяти - только на хранение массивов.

Comment: Можно подробнее расписать как найти такое число X, что то не очень ясно.

Comment: Вам знакомо понятие бинарного поиска? Берете начальное значение `X=(SMin+Smax)/2` и проверяете, какой статистикой оно является. Если число слишком велико, оно будет `p`-й статистикой, где `p<k`, и следующий этап проводится с меньшим значением `X = (X + SMin)/2` и т.д.

Comment: Знакомо понятие бинарного поиска,только тут он застосовуется не в очень явном виде,спасибо.